# What does CkC mean in chemical bonding?

Tags: bond

I'm working on a chemistry question where I'm supposed to use average bond energies to estimate enthalpy changes for a reaction. It gives me these bond energies to work with:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{C-H}&=&413\\
\ce{C-C}&=&348\\
\ce{C-Br}&=&276\\
\ce{H-Br}&=&366\\
\ce{CkC}&=&614\\
\end{align}$$
I know how to do the question, but I don't what $\ce{CkC}$ is. I can't find it online or in my textbook. What does the "k" mean?

Comment: Which text book did you find this notation in? The info will help future visitors having similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\ce{C=C}$ **average bond energy** is somewhere around $\pu{614 kJ/mol}$ so "k" probably indicates a double bond